# how to select icons created dynamically in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am doing a test using Cypress
and I have this rows created dynamically, like this one for example:

[image: example table with dropdown icon to the right]

And what I want is to be able to click on the right icon and show or hide the info, each at the time.

I've inserted `data-cy= selectorName` and the behavior I want to do is:

1. click on first icon (open content)
2. do some test
3. click on first icon again (close content)
4. click on second icon (open content)

...and so fort.

I was assuming only two rows of my table and I did it like:

`cy.get('selector:first').click()` or `cy.get('selector:last').click();` but I need it to work for more rows

Comment: I just came up with the idea of selecting all and iterating? or there is a better way?

Comment: Can you share your code snippet and html of the dynamic table?

Comment: I add a solution that fits. the selector is the same in every html, a data-cy= name, and I got it many times, first case was twice but need it to make it to work with more cases

Answer (score 0):

The approach that works for me :
`cy.get(selector).eq(position).click();`

Answer (score 0):

[You could use `.each()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each) to iterate through an array of elements yielded by your `cy.get()`.

```js
cy.get('foo').each(($el, index) => {
  cy.wrap($el).click();
  ...
  // more tests here
  ...
  cy.wrap($el).click();
});
```